# Table of contents in bold

Tags: table-of-contents

I have in bold only Resumen and Abstract. How can I make the rest look in bold?. I'm already getting the chapters and sections in bold. What's wrong is that List of Symbols, Figures, Abbreviations and tables are not in bold.

in my main.tex:

```
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols, title = Lista de S\'imbolos   ]
\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations,title = Lista de Abreviaturas]
```

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\let\LaTeXStandardTableOfContents\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\begingroup%
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\relax}%
\LaTeXStandardTableOfContents%
\endgroup%
}%

\chapterstyle{dash}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section[First section]{First Section of 1st chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{First Section of 2nd chapter}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memoir class provides it's own mechanism to style the ToC:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterpagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionpagefont}{\bfseries}

\chapterstyle{dash}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section[First section]{First Section of 1st chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{First Section of 2nd chapter}


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With `tocloft` and the `book` class:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand*{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\cftsecpagefont}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section[First section]{First Section of 1st chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{First Section of 2nd chapter}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using the book class :(

Comment: I'm already getting the chapters and sections in bold. What's wrong is that List of Symbols, Figures, Abbreviations and tables are not in bold.

Comment: @NaveganTeX - Out of curiosity: Why do you post a MWE using the memoir class, if you are actually using another class??? Anyway, in that case, you can use `tocloft` which implements the same functionality for other classes.

Comment: Because the Book class is being used for my main thesis. For the MWE I just used the memoir, but I could've used the Book class as well